# Issue when casting to and from a void pointer C++

Tags: c#, c++, box2d, void-pointers

I'm currently working on a C# compatible DLL for Box2D, and am trying to make two separate methods - one for creating a Shape and another for creating a Fixture.

The fixture needs to be given a shape in order to be initialised, so once the Shape is created in its method, it is cast to a void pointer and sent back to C# to be stored as an IntPtr. Then this is passed to the Fixture creation method when required and converted back into a body from a pointer. The code I'm using is this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* CreateBoxShape(float width, float height,
float centreX, float centreY, float angle) {
b2Vec2 centre = b2Vec2(centreX, centreY);
b2PolygonShape* shape;
shape->SetAsBox(width, height, centre, angle);
return static_cast<void*>(shape);
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void* AddFixture(void* bodyPointer, void* shapePointer, float density) {
b2Body* m_body = static_cast<b2Body*>(bodyPointer);
b2Fixture* m_fixture;

b2PolygonShape* aShape = static_cast<b2PolygonShape*>(shapePointer);
b2PolygonShape shape = *aShape;
m_fixture = m_body->CreateFixture(&shape, density);

return static_cast<void*>(m_fixture);
```

}

As you can guess, it's not working. The shape is getting modified somewhere along the way. I'm not used to working with void pointers or static_casts so I'd appreciate any help/suggestions. The constructor for CreateFixture is:

```
b2Fixture * CreateFixture (const b2Shape *shape, float32 density)
```

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable that will cease to exist after the function returns.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Oh, you're right. That's embarrassing. I've changed it. Code's still not working though - I'm certain it's the void pointer stuff but I can't really wrap my head around it.

Comment: now your code is using an unitialized pointer to call a function on it and returns that pointer... maybe some coffee?

Comment: @user3767203 No, it's not the "void pointer stuff", it's the "pointer stuff". Perhaps you should reach for your C++ book for a refresher?

Comment: Ah, ok. All fixed now. Thanks for the help. I've been using C# for the last few months so I guess my C++ memory is a still a little creaky.

Comment: what about b2PolygonShape* shape=new b2PolygonShape;  ... return (void*)(shape); ... but the app should delete it after stop using it of coarse